# New Soffit Vent Design Still Bad Idea?

Tags: hvac, bathroom, roof, ventilation, roofing

I recently discovered that my 1-story ranch (hip roof) has both full baths venting to attic. Upon this discovery I’ve been trying to determine best approach for venting to outside. I’d prefer to not cut two more holes in my roof, as I worry about future leaks, but have seen horror stories of soffit venting in the North East.

More recently, I saw a new soffit vent design for bath exhausts that I’d like opinions on. My main concern is exhausted air being pulled back in by nearby soffit vents (for attic circulation). It appears this design may mitigate this risk? I’ve attached the picture of the design.

[image]

Comment: I can't imagine enough moisture being drawn back into the soffit area to cause a problem, but I also haven't seen "horrors" from soffit venting. I'm not sure what you expect besides speculation.

Comment: Safest place to put vents is on the ridge - no roof above the vent minimizes the opportunity for leaks. I'm not overly thrilled with that looking like it cuts the vent area in half, and then cuts that in half again with the grille, so it would appear to be very restricted and have a lot of back-pressure.

Comment: That looks like it would make a lot of condensation on the aluminium fascia and gutter. However it is better that the humid air being released in the attic. Not the best option, but  I would consider it the lesser of the evils.

Comment: After the exhausted air leaves the house envelope, it's pretty well mixed with outside air.  I wouldn't be worried about moist air being sucked back into the attic.  I don't really see the benefit of that type of vent vs. a simple downward exit from the soffit.

Comment: I’ve seen posts and pictures of mold growth on underside of roof sheathing from people trying to vent bath fan through soffit. I also know that venting through ridge vent is a code violation. Seems like too many opinions to really make a decision.

Comment: @RMDman I agree with you, I had a similar thought about the condensation  too. What is the “best option”?